# strange shutdown behaviour

Tags: shutdown, hdmi

Usually, when I plug in stuff (mostly hdmi cable) the laptop fails to shutdown. What happens is the following: I unplug everything, I try to shutdown from gui (or terminal), but at the very end of the shutdown process (i.e. when I read [number...] reboot: shutdown) the laptop freezes.

I already tried to change in some ways the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash acpi_osi=... etc in the grub but it seems it does not affect the behaviour.

I do not know where to start fixing the problem, since the laptop freezes and I get no additional information on what is not working.

I am using Debian 8 if that may help.

Edit:

```
 lspci | grep VGA
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT        Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Comment: please add info about brand/model of graphic card, and name of linux distro

Comment: added the output of lspci | grep vga is that ok? the distro is debian 8

Comment: so no solution for this? :(

Comment: If you  google around you will see you are not alone. There are actually bugs registered in the kernel for graphic cards, though not necessarily for your model. I would try kernel 4 from the backports to see if the situation goes away, otherwise it will be a tough cookie to debug. A possible avenue will be sending the logs to a remote machine and try to make it happening, and with luck, maybe you got some error machine.

Comment: I see... does  installing kernel 4 have any disadvantages? I never did something like that before